# Swift - How to pass data from VC A to B after VC B is presented?

Tags: swift, pass-data

I have 2 ViewControllers, A and B. ViewController A uses sockets and updates its data whenever changes occur.

How can I pass those updated data to ViewController B when it's already presented (programmatically) by A?

I'm thinking to pass ViewController A's update handler class to ViewController B and take advantage of the fact that classes are reference-type, so any change would happen to A's handler, it would also happen to B's. Is it a valid architectural choice?

Comment: I think he meant the other way round.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/3030400

Answer (score 1):

You just need to maintain a reference to `ViewControllerB` in `ViewControllerA` when you're presenting `ViewControllerB` in `ViewControllerA`, here's how:

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    var viewControllerB: ViewControllerB?

    func presentViewControllerB() {
        if let viewControllerB = viewControllerB {
            present(viewControllerB, animated: true)
        } else {
            viewControllerB = ViewControllerB()
            presentViewControllerB()
        }
    }

    func passDataToViewControllerB() {
        viewControllerB?.someData = "Data from ViewControllerA."
    }
}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    var someData = ""
}
```

Comment: No issues here (No memory leaks). Since you're planning to present view controller there's already a reference being created. Here you're using the same reference to pass on data. Also, it's a one-way connection, so no reference cycles are occurring here.

Comment: What if I passed the data with a NotificationCenter observer?

Comment: It's your choice really. There are plenty of methods.